# kendo listbox select multiple list items

Tags: jquery, angular, kendo-ui, telerik

I am using kendo listbox and I can only find a way to select multiple items with [jQuery](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listbox/configuration/selectable). I tried the following with Angular

```
<kendo-listbox [data]="dataUnselected" [toolbar]="toolbarSettings" textField="displayName" 
    [selectable]="'multiple'" (actionClick)="onActionClicked($event)" class="myClass">
```

But I get an error that says: Can't bind to 'selectable' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-listbox'.

Here is the documentation for [Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/listbox/api/) and I can't find the answer
Is there a way to do the same with Angular?